# Understanding "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

[In this commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/6e066a4db72ff6b0d12dd8a43faec0a80e4a1fed#L0L31) there is a change I cannot explain

```
deferred.done.apply( deferred, arguments ).fail.apply( deferred, arguments );
```

becomes

```
deferred.done( arguments ).fail( arguments );
```

[AFAIK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#section_5), when you invoke a function as a member of some object like `obj.func()`, inside the function `this` is bound to `obj`, so there would be no use invoking a function through `apply()` just to bound `this` to `obj`. Instead, according to the comments, this was required because of some preceding `$.Callbacks.add` implementation.

My doubt is not about jQuery, but about the Javascript language itself: when you invoke a function like `obj.func()`, how can it be that inside `func()` the `this` keyword **is not bound** to `obj`?

Comment: How is that commit change related to your question at all? `.apply` was used to pass `n` amount of arguments to another function, not for its context forcing abilities.

Comment: @Esailija, I think you got the point!

Comment: @Christoph I think he got the point. apply() was not used to force the context, since *this* was already *placed correctly* (and this answers my question)

Comment: The side effect of using `.apply` of course is that it's called as a property of `.done/.fail` instead of `.deferred` so you also need to pass the right context but it's not the main point of using it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My doubt is not about jQuery, but about the Javascript language
>   itself: when you invoke a function like obj.func(), how can it be that
>   inside func() the this keyword is not bound to obj?

Well, the only way this is possible is if `obj.func` references a [`bound`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function, then it doesn't matter how you call it. In that case it doesn't matter how you call the function, whether you do `obj.func()`, `func()`, `func.call({})`, `func.apply({})` doesn't matter at all. I'm not sure how the commit is related to this, however.

To clarify, I am answering the quoted question interpreted as:

Given a call signature like: `obj.func()`, how is it possible that `this` is **not** `obj` inside the called function for the call?

Comment: Great answer. I wonder if you just guessed or if you knew that $.Callbacks.add can't handle arguments passed as an array like :)

Comment: @Raffaele In fact, neither. It's just that `.apply( something, arguments)` is the only way to pass arguments around exactly as they were passed to the calling function. Well, I suppose you could do something with `eval` but that doesn't count :D

Comment: This is even greater :) So the key was you recognized the **arguments** keyword in the construct *.apply(smth, arguments)* and immediately linked this to calls chaining. Often to solve tricky problems one needs deep knowledge of the subject (experience) and *lateral thinking* :)

Answer (score 5):

While the other answers deal with your question about the `this` keyword, they don't answer your question of why `apply` is being used. Here's the kicker: `apply` is not being used to set the `this` keyword in that example.  Instead, it's being used to pass `arguments` as the arguments of the `done` and `fail` functions.

Take this example:

```
var x = {
    a: function(a1, a2, a3) {
        console.log(a1, a2, a3);
    }
}

function callA() {
    x.a.apply(x, arguments);
    x.a(arguments);
}

callA('red', 'blue', 'green');
```

If you execute this code you should see the difference between `x.a.apply(x, arguments);` and `x.a(arguments);`. In the first one, `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` are the respective colors "red", "blue", and "green". In the second one, `a1` is an array-like object `[ "red", "blue", "green" ]` and `a2` and `a3` are `undefined`.

Likewise, in your posted example, `apply` is being used to pass the `arguments` object correctly, not to set the `this` keyword.

Comment: +1, sorry this can't be the accepted one, but Esailija's got first (plus he mentioned bound objects). However I really appreciate the clarity, and hope your code sample can help others understand the real question as you did :)

Answer (score 2):

That is only possible by referencing the function from another Object like so

```
obj2.func = obj.func;
obj2.func(); // 'this' now refers to obj2

var func2 = obj.func;
func2(); // 'this' now refers to the global window object
```

or by calling .apply() or .call() to bind `this` to any arbitrary object.

Comment: This is right, but doesn't answer my question :) I wanted to know the difference, with regards to **this** bounding, between *a.b(args)* and *a.b.apply(b, args)* See @wnwall answer

Comment: I *did* answer your question: "when you invoke a function like obj.func(), how can it be that inside func() the this keyword is not bound to obj?" :-) What you state as being your question is not in the top post: maybe you should update it!

Comment: I don't think so :P In fact, your example never calls *func* as a member of *obj*: it happens to invoke the same function object, but as the property of another object (either *obj2* or *window*). So  the value of *this* is predictable and expected. Instead, I asked if when the engine executes *a.b()* there is any chance that, inside *b()*, *this != a*.

Comment: Ah then I misinterpreted the word "like" in the sentence "a function like obj.func()" as meaning "similar to"... Then you're correct about the first part of my answer, and only the second part about .call() and .apply() is relevant :-)

Answer (score 1):

A function is always called with a receiver, called `this` inside the function, which is given at call.

When you're writing

```
obj.someFunc = function() {...
```

you're not saying that someFunc must have as receiver obj, you're just saying that obj has a property called someFunc whose value is a function.

If you do

```
var aFunc = obj.someFunc;
```

like is done in many places (referencing of callback for example) and after that

```
 aFunc();
```

the receiver (`this`) is in this case the window.

That's because functions, in javascript, contrary to languages like java, are "first class" objects, meaning in particular that you can pass them as values and aren't bound to a unique prespecified receiver.

Comment: See @Esailija and answers. What you said is correct, but it doesn't address the question, since I explicitely linked the source code and the function is really definetely as obj.func()

Comment: Thanks for you comment pointing to Esailija's answer. You're perfectly right.

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand version I use is that `this` in JavaScript always refers to the object of which the currently executing function is a method--except in the special case when the method is a callback, when `this` refers to the object to which the callback is bound (e.g. a button).

**Edit**:  note that a global function is like a method of the `window` object.

[This QuirksMode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) helped me when I was learning about it.